# Alternatives for SharePoint:InputFormTextBox in Google Chrome and Firefox

Tags: 2010, asp.net, aspx, inputformtextbox

We use `SharePoint:InputFormTextBox` in our SP 2010 application. Now the requirement is to make it work in Google Chrome and Firefox also. But from what I read the `SharePoint:InputFormTextBox` control is only supported on IE.

Are there any alternative for `SharePoint:InputFormTextBox` which work on Google Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

To view the `SharePoint:InputFormTextBox` control in Firefox and Chrome browser may cause issues that make the control not render properly. This control works well only with IE browser. To overcome this, there is a JavaScript code snippet available as explained in this article:

[SharePoint Rich Text Input Control](http://sharepointerz.blogspot.qa/2012/07/sharepoint-rich-text-input-control.html)

Put the code given in above article link in the html part of your page where you are using this `InputFormTextBox` control.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this external (cross platform) content editor: http://nicedit.com/index.php 
and it worked perfectly for me.

And it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I have an application page with user Control. I tried to use nicedit in User Control but it's not working. Could you please share us how you did it ?.